# I want to make it so that each product will have a link, and the link will link to a page with the product's info

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am working on a django project.

Here is my `models.py` file:

```
class Product(request):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    cost = models.FloatField(max_length=255)
    info = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
```

Here is my `views.py` file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Product

def index(request):
    products = Product.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'index.html',
                  {'products': products})

# I know the below is incorrect, but I don't know how to correct it.

def information(request):
    info = Product.objects.all()
    return HttpResponse(info[products.index(product)].info)
```

Here is my `index.html` file:

```
{% for product in products %}
    <l1>{{product.name}} ${{ product.price }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

I want to make it so that each product will have a link, and the link will link to a page with the product's info. How can I dynamically do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion would be to use django's built-in generic views, they are very useful.

So first, you need a `ListView` to list all your products, for example:

```
from django.views import generic
class ProductList(generic.ListView):
    model = models.Product
    template_name = 'products/product_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'product_list'
```

And then a `DetailView`:

```
class ProductDetail(generic.DetailView):
    model = models.Product
    template_name = 'products/product_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'product'
```

Now in your list template you can do as follows:

```
{% if product_list %}
{% for product in product_list %}
<a href="{% url 'products:detail' pk=product.pk %}"> {{product.name}} </a>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

And on your detail template you can do something similar to show for example the cost and the info. Obviously this is just an example, and you would have to change it to suit your needs. But this should help you get started. For more information, you can also refer to the documentation on this:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/